Gmsh not building when using FetchContent
I am a computer science student and want to write a project in c++ using gmsh api https://gitlab.onelab.info/gmsh/gmsh
When I clone the gmsh repo and build it as dynamically linked library everything works just fine. The build finished and the examples execute.
However when I set up another project and try to use the gmsh api as a third party library there are plenty of linker errors, fe:
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles/shared.dir/objects.a(gmsh.cpp.obj):gmsh.cpp:(.rdata$.refptr._ZTV11MQuadrangle[.refptr._ZTV11MQuadrangle]+0x0): undefined reference to `vtable for MQuadrangle'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles/shared.dir/objects.a(Numeric.cpp.obj):Numeric.cpp:(.text+0xfa7c): undefined reference to `Ei
gen::internal::first_aligned_impl<16, Eigen::CwiseBinaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_conj_product_op<double, double>, Eigen::Transpose<Eigen::Block<Eigen::Transpose<Eigen::Block<Eigen::Block<Eigen::Matrix<do
uble, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1>, -1, -1, false>, -1, -1, false> const> const, 1, -1, true> const> const, Eigen::Block<Eigen::Ref<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1>, 0, Eigen::InnerStride<1> > const, -1, 1, tr
ue> const>, true>::run(Eigen::CwiseBinaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_conj_product_op<double, double>, Eigen::Transpose<Eigen::Block<Eigen::Transpose<Eigen::Block<Eigen::Block<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1, 0
, -1, -1>, -1, -1, false>, -1, -1, false> const> const, 1, -1, true> const> const, Eigen::Block<Eigen::Ref<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1>, 0, Eigen::InnerStride<1> > const, -1, 1, true> const> const&)'

In the root directory I have CMakeLists.txt file:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.26)

set(PROJECT_NAME FEM_project)

project(
        ${PROJECT_NAME}
        VERSION 2.0.0
        LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

include(FetchContent)
FetchContent_Declare(gmsh
        GIT_REPOSITORY https://gitlab.onelab.info/gmsh/gmsh
        GIT_TAG gmsh_4_13_1)
set(ENABLE_BUILD_DYNAMIC ON)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(gmsh)

target_link_options(shared PUBLIC "-lgmp")
target_link_options(shared PUBLIC "-lwsock32")
target_link_options(shared PUBLIC "-lWs2_32")
target_link_options(shared PUBLIC "-lAdvApi32")
target_link_libraries(shared Ws2_32)
target_link_libraries(shared wsock32)
target_link_libraries(shared AdvApi32)

add_subdirectory(src)
target_link_libraries(
        ${PROJECT_NAME}
        PUBLIC
        shared
)

In the source directory there is just a main.cpp file with copy-pasted content of the first tutorial.
In the CMakeLists.txt I just ad the file to the project:
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp)

I run the code on Windows 11.
It seems that for some reason the Eigen package (which I guess is a copy-paste from original source to the contrib directory) doesn't link properly.
The same happens when I try to link the library statically.
I tried to link the eigen and eigen_blas_static with target_link_libraries but it doesn't help.

target_link_options(shared PUBLIC "-lAdvApi32") - target_link_libraries(shared AdvApi32) why do you repeat that, do the same differently?

Neither of target_link_* links with gmsh.

Yeah the doubled linkings for those libraries are relevant.

Neither of target_link_* links with gmsh. Yeah, cuz this is the target's name when I want to compile it as dll. When I try to link the gmsh with target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC gmsh) to my project there is a cmake error saying that I can't link an executable to a target.

For building a dll you must set ENABLE_BUILD_SHARED to ON. ENABLE_BUILD_DYNAMIC - is "Enable dynamic Gmsh executable"
